# javascript cookie doesn't set expire date

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using a cookie in JavaScript to remember the last position on a map, but I just realise that the cookie miss the expire date even if I added.

Here you can test the code

https://www.traffwebdemo.co.uk/parking/basic.html

Here my code, for some reason the only one that accept the expire date (and is actually present if I inspect the cookie) is Opera, the other browsers seems to miss the expire date or they say expire on session (FF).

```
const setUserPrefs = (mapView) => {
  let cookieStr
  const curZ = mapView.getView().getResolution()
  const mapCen = mapView.getView().getCenter()
  const expdate = new Date()

  // set expire date to one week
  expdate.setTime(expdate.getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))

  cookieStr = `#${mapCen[0]}#${mapCen[1]}#${curZ}`

  document.cookie = `traffweb${window.location.href}= ${escape(cookieStr)}, expires=${expdate.toUTCString()} path=/`
}
```

How can I make work this code?

if I use decodeURIComponent(document.cookie); yes I have the cookie exp date but not if I go to application in the dev tools and I don't need to check if is set or not to be honest, simply close the browser and reopen it in the same link and the map is not on the same position, it work just on session.

Comment: In chrome I get your ugly cookie with `%23508000%23182700%232.8, expires=Thu, 23 May 2019 13:10:14 GMT path=/` I strongly suggest you do NOT make the location.href part of the NAME of the cookie

Comment: for the purpose I need this cookie I need the href in the name as the customer have 2 sites `/main.html` and `/consult/main.html` or more so I want to memorise the last position on each map. that apart I don't see the date on my Chrome, neither on FF and it doesn't work in IE neither if I close the browser and I reopen the page. the only one is Opera.

Comment: update, if I use decodeURIComponent(document.cookie); yes I have the cookie exp date but not if I go to `application` in the dev tools

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean

Comment: at the time of publication i didn't know that was actually set if it asked via javascript I was just testing it closing the browser and open it again and is not  working

Comment: Just NEVER set your own cookies. Use a library that is tested such as https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie - your content breaks the cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just NEVER set your own cookies. Use a library that is tested such as https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie - your content breaks the cookie

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

using

```
let cookieName = location.href.split("/").slice(-2); 
cookieName.pop(); // get rid of file name
const curZ = mapView.getView().getResolution()
const mapCen = mapView.getView().getCenter()
let cookieStr = `#${mapCen[0]}#${mapCen[1]}#${curZ}`
Cookies.set("traffweb"+cookieName, cookieStr , { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Comment: I'll give it a try before to accept the answer :)  you say that the content breaks the cookie but why in Opera works? sometimes I hate crossbrowser issues

Comment: There are no cross browser issues with wellformed cookies